# Sending Base64 encoded data with URLRequest

Tags: apache-flex, base64

I'm writing functionality to upload an image along with some metadata to a service that is expecting a POST operation with the image encoded in base64. However, the image data seems to get mangled when it is posted to the server, and doesn't produce a valid image. I opted to use the URLRequest framework rather than HTTPService because the service returns an inline download that the user will want to save.

Is there somewhere in this URLRequest call where I'm handling the encoding incorrectly?

```
    public function imageExportHandler():void
    {
        trace(this);
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        request.url = imageExportServiceUrl;

        var params:Object = {
            image: encodeImageBase64(imageData),
            name: StringUtil.substitute("map-{xmin},{ymin}-{xmax},ymax}", imageExtent),
            format: Model.instance.imageExportModel.selectedFormat
        };
        request.data = new URLVariables(StringUtil.substitute("image={image}&format={format}&name={name}", params));
        navigateToURL(request, "_blank");
    }

    private function encodeImageBase64(toEncode:BitmapData):String
    {
        var pngEncoder:PNGEncoder = new PNGEncoder();
        var data:ByteArray = pngEncoder.encode(toEncode);
        var base64Encoder:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();
        base64Encoder.encodeBytes(data);
        return base64Encoder.flush();
    }
```

Comment: Does the Base64 encoder that you are using encode it into a string that is safe for transportation over the web? Characters +, =, and / will cause issues if they are contained by the Base64 string.

Comment: @Ren That might be it. The encoder works reliably with the HTTPService library, but that might be handling url encoding issues behind the scenes.

Comment: I am assuming that the service you mention in your question is not under your control. Do they have any documentation that would point you in the right direction? Perhaps they mention what characters you should change these symbols to? Usually it is `'+' = '%2B', '/' = '%2F' and '=' = '%3D'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that base64Encoder.flush() wasn't properly terminating the encoded string - the correct function to use is base64Encoder.toString().